# Using Microsoft Translator API for for multiple source languages in R

Tags: r, microsoft-translator

I have a large set of Tweets in 51 different languages which I would like to translate to Englisch. The Tweets are organized in a dataframe, where one column is the actual text.

Each row has 17 columns with different information, such as user_id, status_id, language and text. Looking like this:

```
A tibble: 642,581 × 17
   user_id  status_id  created_at screen_name text    source  favorite_count retweet_count quote_count reply_count hashtags
   <chr>    <chr>      <chr>      <chr>       <chr>   <chr>   <chr>          <chr>         <chr>       <chr>       <chr>   
 1 1235580… 138959693… 2021-05-0… China_Lyon  "la bo… "Twitt… 0              15            NA          NA          "c(\"Ch…
 2 NA       135549494… 2021-01-30 Ambassador… "rt : … "<a hr… 0              0             0           0            NA
```

I have an Azure Account due to my university, so I have the Microsoft API key. The translation from one language to english does work with this code:

```
translated_tweets <- translateR::translate(dataset = Tweets,
                                             content.field = 'text', 
                                             microsoft.api.key  = 'my.api.key',
                                             source.lang = 'de',
                                             target.lang = 'en',
                                             microsoft.token = TRUE)
```

My question now is, how would the code look like, if I have multiple source languages? I tried to simply ad another source language, to the one that is already there, but that doesn't work. Would it be better if iterate this code snippet for every different language? Resulting in 51 dataframes, which should then only be merged together?

I am quite new to programming, so please bare with me, if these questions might sound stupid.

Comment: I have never used package `v`but to iterate the languages seems to be an option. `df_list <- lapply(langs, \(ll) translateR::translate(etc, source.lang = ll, etc))`. Then you can bind the dataframes with `translated_tweets<-data.table::rbindlist(df_list)`, a fast function.

Comment: Is the source language really needed? E.g. when using Google translate it will first automatically detect the language. And it‘s usually pretty accurate. I would be suprised if MS wasn‘t doing the same.

Comment: So what happens if you just leave blank the source.lang?

Comment: If I leave the source.lang blank, this is the error I get ```Error in if (!(source.lang %in% unname(unlist(languages["Microsoft"])))) { : 
  Argument length 0```

Comment: @deschen is correct, the API will auto-detect if the source language is missing or an empty string. The library you are using seems to test for a non-empty source.lang string and fails if empty. This check should have an exception to let the empty or null string pass

Comment: Ah okay, is there any other R package I could use to access the Microsoft API? Or is there a possibility to build such a code, that let the source.lang pass?